# XBOX UWP app closes when pressing B twice

Tags: uwp, xbox

I have a UWP app that behaves as expected when pressing back (B), however, when I press B consecutively the app closes and takes me back to the XBOX dash. Any thoughts on how I can prevent it from closing at all when pressing back?

Comment: Can you try [`confirmAppClose`](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/09/app-close-confirmation-in-uwp/)?

Comment: I'll check it out 